# Doctrine update entity with arraycollection dont remove items

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, arraycollection

I have this classes:

AbstractBillingInvoice

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="billing_invoice")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BillingBundle\Repository\AbstractBillingInvoiceRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="billingInvoiceType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"ProFormaInvoice" = "\BillingBundle\Entity\BillingInvoices\ProFormaInvoice", "Invoice" = "\BillingBundle\Entity\BillingInvoices\Invoice"})
 * @GRID\Column(id="billingInvoiceType", filterable=false, type="abstract_billing_invoice")
 * @GRID\Column(id="downloadInvoice", filterable=false, type="download_invoice", safe=false)
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 */
abstract class AbstractBillingInvoice
{
.....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BillingBundle\Entity\BillingInvoiceItem", mappedBy="billingInvoice", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $billingInvoiceItems;
......
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->billingInvoiceItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getBillingInvoiceItems()
    {
        return $this->billingInvoiceItems;
    }

    public function setBillingInvoiceItems($billingInvoiceItems)
    {
        $this->billingInvoiceItems = $billingInvoiceItems;

        return $this;
    }

    public function addBillingInvoiceItems(BillingInvoiceItem $billingInvoiceItems)
    {
        $billingInvoiceItems->setBillingInvoice($this);
        $this->billingInvoiceItems->add($billingInvoiceItems);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBillingInvoiceItems(BillingInvoiceItem $billingInvoiceItems)
    {
        if ($this->billingInvoiceItems->contains($billingInvoiceItems)) {
            $this->billingInvoiceItems->remove($billingInvoiceItems);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

and BillingInvoiceItem

```
class BillingInvoiceItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BillingBundle\Entity\AbstractBillingInvoice", inversedBy="billingInvoiceItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $billingInvoice;
.....
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setBillingInvoice($billingInvoice)
    {
        $this->billingInvoice = $billingInvoice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBillingInvoice()
    {
        return $this->billingInvoice;
    }
```

Everything works fine, except one thing - I am not able to remove items from  collection. There is no problem with add item, but if some item missing, there are two situations - if is removed last element of ArrayCollection, nothing happend in database. If is removed other element, last element is copied instead of it.

If I dump entity AbstractBillingInvoice in EntityListenere in method onFlush, I see data correct. If I remove element, element is really missing, but after flush is this this element back in the database.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much
D

Answer (score 0):

usually we manage Many relations by `ArrayCollection` from `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;` package.

You can update your code like this :

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->billingInvoice = new ArrayCollection();
    // [...]
}
public function getBillingInvoice(){
    return $this->billingInvoice->toArray();
}

public function addBillingInvoice(BillingInvoice $billingInvoice){
    if(!$this->billingInvoice->contains($billingInvoice)){
        $this->billingInvoice->add($billingInvoice);
    }
}

public function removeBillingInvoice(BillingInvoice $billingInvoice){
    if($this->billingInvoice->contains($billingInvoice)){
        $this->billingInvoice->removeElement($billingInvoice);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to remove one relation, juste call :

```
$myEntity->removeBillingInvoice($myBillingInvoice);
$em->persist($myEntity);
$em->flush();
```

But i am not sure if this will fix your initial issue, have you try to check if tou billingInvoice entity have also reverse mapping removed ?

Comment: Hello, there is no problem in remove element from ArrayCollection. Entity before flush is set correctly. But after flush are all invoice item still in the database. Add item is OK, change item too, but remove item not. If I remove last element, nothing happen and if I remove element from middle, last element is set to its place (copied to the its id).

Comment: I have made this fix: $billingInvoiceItemFromDb = $this->billingInvoiceItemRepository->findBy(
                [
                    'billingInvoice' => $entity,
                ]
            );

           
            foreach ($billingInvoiceItemFromDb as $item) {
                if (!$entity->getBillingInvoiceItems()->contains($item)) {
                    $this->billingInvoiceItemRepository->delete($item);
                }
            }

Comment: yes is what i have means about remove reverse mapping. Happy you have solve your issue